# remove invalid parentheses time complexity

Tags: time-complexity

Try to understand running time of below algorithm for problem; `Remove the minimum number of invalid parentheses in order to make the input string valid. Return all possible results`

This is a simple BFS solution that generates all possible strings by removing "(" or ")".

```
public List<String> removeInvalidParentheses(String s) {
    List<String> ret = new LinkedList<>();
    Set<String> visited = new HashSet<>();
    Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    queue.add(s);
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        String current = queue.poll();
        if (isValidParentheses(current)) {
            ret.add(current);
        }
        if (ret.size() > 0) continue;
        for (int i = 0; i < current.length(); i++) {
            if (current.charAt(i) == '(' || current.charAt(i) == ')') {
                String next = current.substring(0, i) + current.substring(i + 1);
                if (!visited.contains(next)) {
                    visited.add(next);
                    queue.offer(next);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

public boolean isValidParentheses(String current) {
    int open = 0;
    int close = 0;
    for (char c : current.toCharArray()) {
        if (c == '(') open++;
        else if (c == ')') close++;
        if (close > open) return false;
    }
    return open == close;
}
```

It starts with generate n possible strings and next level it generate all strings with size n-1 length, and n-2 length, etc .. for `)()(` example

```
                )()(                 len n
      ()(    ))(    ()(    )()       n-1
   () (( ()                          n-2
```

each level it checks all possible strings with n-level length.
given this - I was having hard to time figure out how to finalize the running time of this algorithm. How do I generalize this algorithm and analyze the complexity?

Comment: by "invalid parentheses" do you mean any that are not closed or opened properly? If so, since the hierarchy of brackets is recursive, you should use a *stack*, which would be *DFS* and therefore have O(n) complexity

Answer (score 0):

For the worst case, lets try with input as `((((`. As per the logic above, it will push `((((` in the queue, checking that this is invalid. So it would generate 4 more possible substrings of length 3 pushing them inside the queue. Again, on processing that queue elements, it would again generate more strings of length 2 for each substring of length 3, then for two and then end. We are assuming that T(1) = 1.

If you try to make a recurrence relation for the above logic, it would be

`T(n) = nT(n-1) + 1`, which can be written as

```
     = `n((n-1)T(n-2) + 1) + 1` and so on.
```

On solving it completely, we would get `T(n) = n! + n(n-1)/2 + 1` which would be `O(n!)`.

Hence, I think the time complexity would be of order `O(n!)`
For more details on how to solve the recurrence relation `T(n) = nT(n-1) + 1`, please refer:
[this post on its solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1480899/how-to-solve-recurrence-tn-ntn-1-1)